# How to import my Meteor app files into my packages?

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6

Now that I am defining my collections inside `/imports`, how can I make my packages access them?

- Running `import collections from '/imports/collections'` or `require('/imports/collections')` results in `Error: Cannot find module '/imports/collections'`
- Declaring the dependency with `api.addFiles` is not allowed for files outside of the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages are defined at compile time, the apps collection are defined at run time. You can't access run time data at compile time.

You need to call a constructor for your package, with a list of collections.

```
// packages/myFixturesPackage/startup.js

import collections from '/imports/collections/index.js';

Meteor.startup(

Package['myFixturesPackage'].collections = require('/imports/collections/index.js');

fixtures.populate(Package['myFixturesPackage'].collections); );
```

index.js export a collections array containing all colllections defined in the main app (which is run time for the package), and it is then passed to the module which exposes the fixtures objet.

Comment: the import must run inside the startup function. That's the only way to assure that it will run in runtime
that's why I used require instead of import
the way you wrote in the answer will give me the same error.

Please fix that so I can accept your answer :)

Comment: Done, but.... I read in the meteor commits that if you are not doing conditional imports, then you should be able to do everything with imports. Are you adding this code from the package? or it is in the app? This type of code should be in the app, not the package.